# can I export service area (network analysis) to shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

Is it possible to export service area (network analysis) to shapefile? if so, how can I do it? I am using ArcGIS 10.

Comment: Do you work with a local network dataset or consume an ArcGIS Online service?

Comment: @Alex Tereshenkov I work with a local network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To export a result service area layer to a shapefile or feature class in a geodatabase, you can right-click Polygons sublayer of the network analasis layer (named Service Area by default) and choose Data > Export data.

[image]

Comment: Perfect!!! It does work.