# How do I export to a shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, map-service

I created a new map, connected to my ArcGIS service, and dragged a map from a map service into the Table of Contents. The map is drawn on the screen with all my data points and I can see the attributes of each point when using the Identify tool. How do I export all the points with their attributes to a shapefile?

I tried right-clicking in the ToC, on the points, on the layers... everywhere I could think of for a possible right-click option. I also looked in the ArcToolbox, Conversion Tools but none of the tools seemed like a fit. The source is not a CAD file, Feature Class, Raster, or Table. The closest I found is Feature Class to Shapefile (multiple) but my source is not a Feature Class and all my attempts to use this option with layers files have failed.

ArcMap 10.1

Comment: related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102100/can-i-export-service-area-network-analysis-to-shapefile

Comment: @Mapperz - When I right-click I only see Zoom to Layer, Zoom to make visible, Show Labels, and Properties.

Comment: I retract my answer - copy features used to handle this now I can't get it to run...!

Comment: @DenaliHardtail Is your 'ArcGIS Service' a ArcGIS Server/Enterprise service, or ArcGIS Online?